# HTML select box customizing CSS for disabled selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

how can I customize a select box to show "disabled selected" value customized on page load/refresh, not only after option shown/selected.

```
<select>
  <option>Poland</option>
  <option>Germany</option>
  <option style="color:red" disabled selected>Choose</option>
</select>
```

I tried many CSS solutions, but non works on page loading / refresh.
I also don't want to rebuild the whole select box by hiding the original.
There is any workaround for it?

EDIT:
a more closer approach for what i want is this one:

```
<select id="country" name="country" style="color:red" required>
    <option style="color:red" disabled selected>Choose</option>
    <option style="color:black">Germany</option>
    <option style="color:black">Poland</option>
</select>
```

but i would like to have the selected value to be displayed in it's color and only the disabled option to be showned in different color.

Comment: `I also don't want to rebuild the whole select box by hiding the original` In this case, no. CSS on `select` elements is not very reliable across multiple browsers. To style these controls you normally need to use a third-party library which converts the control to a HTML/JS structure which can have CSS applied to it

Comment: you are probably right since i digging for few days now on this subject and cannot solve it with simple CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make CSS work with :invalid pseudoselector when you have an option with "selected" (even if it's disabled), you should add value="" to each of your options, otherwise the value will fallback to the innerText of the option.

Is that what you want?

```css
select {
  color: black;
}
select:invalid {
  color: red;
}
option {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<select id="country" name="country" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose</option>
    <option value="">Germany</option>
    <option value="">Poland</option>
</select>
```

Comment: its strange, it works here on this code snippet but not on my test.html :( (tested with chrome, firefox and edge)

Comment: Can you share the full contents of your test.html file?

Comment: Did you add the value="" attribute I mentioned?

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <!-- Load external CSS styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>

<!-- Form starting here -->
<form id="register_form" method="post" role="form" action="#">

<select id="country" name="country" required>
  <option disabled selected>Choose</option>
  <option value="10">Germany</option>
  <option value="11">Poland</option>
  <option value="12">United Kingdom</option>
</select>

</form>  
  <!-- Form ending here -->
 
     </body>
</html>

Comment: and the CSS file contains: select {
  color: black;
}
select:invalid {
  color: red;
}
option {
  color: black;
}

Comment: You should add value="" to the disabled selected <option>, value="" means empty/undefined in this case. More explanations and the working code is here: https://codepen.io/c-plus-plus-equals-c-plus-one/pen/JjvwQob

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do in simple way but not the better you can do something like this

```css
option{
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<select style="color: red">
  <option>Poland</option>
  <option>Germany</option>
  <option disabled selected>Choose</option>
```

Comment: i thought only about the disabled value to be different. the solution offered by you makes colored the whole list even after selection where made. If you look at my code snippet, you will see, that only the selected value is colored but unfortunately only when the drop down list is opened.. I want to see it colored even when the page is loaded, not only upon selection.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the option using the 'hidden' attribute. The 'Choose' option will be shown as the default/selected option on page load, but it will be hidden in the dropdown options and will not be shown/selectable from the options once the user selects any of the options .

```html
<select>
  <option>Poland</option>
  <option>Germany</option>
  <option hidden selected>Choose</option>
</select>
```

Output:
[image: Output].

Comment: i dont want to hide it (or is not matter), but i want to see it colored different when the page is loaded

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're talking about removing that grey background for the option with "disabled" and "selected" when you just open the select on page load.

This code below removes the default browser-specific (blue in Chrome) background color from the HTML  in the .

Is it what you want?

That's the only way to build it in a more "native" way with , instead of building custom lists to mock a .

You can play around with different styles, it's very customizable.

```js
const optionsSelect = document.querySelector('select[name="options"]');
const options = optionsSelect.querySelectorAll('option');

optionsSelect.size = options.length;

const placeholderSelect = document.querySelector('input.placeholder-select');
optionsSelect.onchange = function ({target}) {
  placeholderSelect.value = options[target.selectedIndex].innerText;
}

options.forEach(() => {  optionsSelect.classList.toggle("focused");
});
placeholderSelect.onclick = function () {  optionsSelect.classList.toggle("focused");
}


document.body.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
if (["INPUT", "SELECT", "OPTION"].includes(e.target.tagName)) {
  return;
}
optionsSelect.classList.contains("focused") && optionsSelect.classList.remove("focused");
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
select[name="options"].focused {
  display: block;
}
input.placeholder-select {
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  border: 1px solid #FDE3FF;
  padding: 6px;
}
.placeholder-select-wrapper:after {
  content: attr(label);
  color: black;
}
.custom-select-group {
flex-direction: column;
display: flex;
}
select:focus {
  outline: none;
}
select[name="options"] {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
}
option:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px #ffb7b7 inset;
}
option {
  border: green;
  padding: 6px;
  color: white;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
option:checked {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px lightpink inset;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-select-group">
     <input autofocus="off" value="Option 3" class="placeholder-select" />
  </select>
  
  <select size="3" name='options'>
  <option value='option-1' class="options">Option 1</option>
     <option value='option-2' class="options">Option 2</option>
     <option selected disabled value='option-3' class="options">Option 3</option>
  </select>  
</div>
```

This also refers to "Remove blue background from option in select HTML CSS JS JavaScript", "Custom styles for option in select"

Comment: Sometimes is harder to write down what you want than do it efectively. I want when you fill your options to have a general overview of uncompleted/unselected options and though about a different initial color will help me in this way. I'm doing a wrong approach?

Comment: Proszę pisać po polsku. Znam polski. Czy ty jesteś Polakiem?

Also, does this code below help?

select option:selected {
  color: red;
}
select option {
  color: black;
}

It would be helpful if you could also draw a simple picture of what you'd like it to look like in different states

Comment: Or would you like the selectbox's value to be in a specific color depending on whether the option selected is disabled or no?

Comment: I mean the color of the <select> "label", not the <option>'s label color. Do you want to change the color when the select is not expanded (you mentioned "on page load"), right?

Comment: This is possible with a few lines of JS

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have > 2 colors, you can use this JS below:

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select[name="country"]#country');

const setColor = () => {
select.style.color = select.querySelectorAll('option')[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute('set-color');

}

setColor();

select.onchange = () => setColor();
```

```css
option {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<select id="country" name="country" required>
    <option set-color="red" disabled selected value="">Choose</option>
    <option set-color="black" value="">Germany</option>
    <option set-color="green"
    value="">Poland</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In css (hope you mean this)

```
option:disabled{
  color: red;
}
```